# How to use .htaccess to rewrite requests from image to PHP script?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a PHP script located at `http://sb1.dev.codeanywhere.net/~a70097sb/hc/onlinestatus/image.php` that requires two `GET` variables: `ign` and `style`. My `.htaccess` file is in the same directory as `image.php`.

I want requests of the form `http://sb1.dev.codeanywhere.net/~a70097sb/hc/onlinestatus/{style}/{ign}.png` to be rewritten to `http://sb1.dev.codeanywhere.net/~a70097sb/hc/onlinestatus/image.php?style={style}&ign={ign}`. How do I do this, as I have no experience with mod_rewrite, and wasn't able to get it to work using any of the tutorials I found on Google.

Tried this but it didn't work, I just get a 404 page:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^.]*)/([^.]*)\.png$ image.php?style=$1&ign=$2 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track.  The capture pattern `([^/]+)` matches everything up to the next `/`, so you'll need two of those.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.png$ image.php?style=$1&ign=$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Neither answer seems to be working. See my updated question, I included the actual site because I think it might have something to do with the subdomains. I added `~a70097sb/` to the beginning of each of those paths too and it still didn't work.

Comment: @DC_ see my update - sorry, I missed the part about your .htaccess being in the `image.php` directory.

Comment: Still isn't working: http://sb1.dev.codeanywhere.net/~a70097sb/hc/onlinestatus/test/test.png

Comment: @DC_ You need to look in your server's error log to see what the actual 500 error is.

Comment: Check it now, should be back to 404. The 500 error was from when I was messing around with it.

Comment: I suspect the htaccess may not be read at all. Add a redirect rule to verify `RewriteRule .* http://www.google.com [L,R]`  Also add the `[R]` flag to the end of your rule to force a full browser redirect and see if it is building the correct URL.

Comment: The google redirect worked, and I think now we're getting somewhere. When I added `[R]` to the original rule, it appears apache is trying to load the path with public_html in it, causing the 404.

Comment: I finally got it working by altering the path. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com [NC]
   RewriteRule ^hc\/onlinestatus\/(.*)\/(.*)\.png /hc/onlinestatus/image.php?style=$1&ign=$2 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```