# PHP - Rewrite the requested png to a php

Tags: php, .htaccess

My url will look something like this:

```
mysite.com/testing/img.png?text1=hey&text2=bye
```

How will I make it so that img.png is actually image.php with the `$_GET`'s being `text1` and `text2` using `.htaccess`?

Comment: [**This**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11405651/2518525) is practically the same thing you're requesting. (*with a few modifications of course*)

Comment: I'm not very good with htaccess so I wouldn't know how to edit it to that :(

Comment: More information, please! Do you want to rewrite these URLs to a PHP file? And this file must receive text1 and text2 in the $_GET variable?

Comment: Yes! So img.png?text1=hey&text2=bye would rewrite to something like image.php?text1=hey&text2=bye but the url would stay as img.png

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job. and you'll get also the extension of your requested file.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^img.php - [L]

RewriteRule ^img(.*)$ img.php?extension=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, and how would that retrieve the values?

Comment: The values are passed with the option QSA [see documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) and you have to modify the rewrite base, if you want it working in the folder testing...